# Trying to scroll incrementally down and incrementally up when reach bottom of div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a div with a height of auto and would like to have a button that when you click it it incrementally scrolls down until you reach bottom, when the bottom is reached it incrementally  scrolls back up till it reaches the top of the div and then scrolls back down again once it reaches the top.

Here is the jQuery I have so far.

```
function scrollMe() {
var iend = 'false';
var dd = 'down';
var si = $('.scroll-indicator');
var j = $('#textarea').scrollTop();
    if(j == 0){
        console.log('at the top');
        dd = 'down'
    }
    else if(j >= 800){
        dd = 'up';
        console.log('at the bottom');
    }

if(dd == 'down'){
    si.on('click', function(){
        console.log(iend);
        console.log(dd);
        var y = $('#textarea').scrollTop();  //your current y position on the page
        $('#textarea').scrollTop(y+150);
    });
}
else{
    si.on('click', function(){
        console.log(iend);
        var y = $('#textarea').scrollTop();  //your current y position on the page
        $('#textarea').scrollTop(y-150);
    });
}    

// alert when end is reached of scroll
    $('#textarea').bind('scroll', function(){
      if($(this).scrollTop() + 
         $(this).innerHeight()
         >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
      {
        iend = 'true';
        dd = 'up';
        si.addClass('scrollUp');

      }
      else{
        iend = 'false';
        si.removeClass('scrollUp');
      }
    });
}scrollMe();
```

Here is the html

```
    <div class="row row-nopadding hook" id="app-info" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="scroll-indicator"></div>
                <div class="auto" id="textarea">
                  <article class="pl15">
                    <p><strong>Do not use on rabbits or animals other than dogs.</strong> Do not allow your dog to ingest this product. Do not use on puppies under 12 weeks of age. Use entire contents of tube vial on each dog. Do not split one tube between dogs. Do not use multiple tubes on one dog. Weigh your dog to be sure you are applying the right dose formulated for the weight of your dog. Separate the treated dog from all other dogs and cats for 24 hours after treatment has been applied.</p>

                    <p>Monitor your dog after application. The most common signs of ingestion are excessive salivation and foaming at the mouth. If these symptoms occur, immediately feed your dog and continue to monitor your dog for the next 24 hours. Some dogs may experience temporary startle effects when any product is applied. Dogs may experience some temporary irritation at the site of product aplication such as redness, scratching or other signs of discomfort. If signs of sensibility occur, bathe your dog with a mild soap and rinse with large amounts of water. If signs persist or become more severe within a few days of application, consult a veterinarian immediately by calling 1-800-660-1842. If your dog has an unusual reaction to the initial application, consult a veterinarian before repeating application.</p>

                    <p><strong>DO NOT USE ON CATS:</strong> May be toxic and POTENTIALLY FATAL if applied to or ingested by a cat. Keep cats away from treated dogs for 24 hours. Cats that actively groom or engage in a close physical contact with treated dog may be at risk of serious harmful effects. Cats exhibiting signs of ingestion such as excessive salivation and foaming at the mouth should be taken to the veterinarian immediately.</p>
                  </article>
                </div>
              </div><!-- END OF ROW-NOPADDING -->
            </div><!-- END OF COL-SM-5 ROW-NOPADDING -->
```

Any help with figuring this out would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating your code and what you have so far?  From your code I can't see where `scrollMe()` is being called or your `button` etc..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AqM5Y/

Comment: Are you wanting the whole page to scroll or just the #textarea div and have it's overflow be hidden?

Comment: have its overflow be hidden

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the `.animate()` function to scroll your div up and down.

```
$("#textarea").animate({scrollTop: amountToScroll},3000,);
```

I animate the scrollTop of the textarea div down based on the height of the contents minus the height of the #teaxtarea.

```
var amountToScroll = $(".pl15").height() - $("#textarea").height();
```

Then i animate it back up to 0 were it started.

I'm calling scrollMe function inside the `.animate()` function when it completes. It could go on in an endless loop if you wanted it too. But i stopped it with a counter after three times.

```
if(counter <= 2)
   scrollMe();
   counter++;
```

Below is the code and here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/AqM5Y/1/), I hope this is what you were looking for.

```
$(function(){
    var $si = $('.scroll-indicator');
    var down = true;
    var counter = 0;
    var scrollLoop;
    $si.click(function(){
        scrollMe();        
    });

    function scrollMe() {

        var amountToScroll = $(".pl15").height() - $("#textarea").height();

        if(down){ 
            $("#textarea").animate({scrollTop: amountToScroll},3000,
                function(){
                    if(counter <= 2)
                        scrollMe();
                    counter++;
                }
            ); 
            down = false;
        }
        else{
            $("#textarea").animate({scrollTop: 0},3000,function(){
                if(counter <= 2)
                    scrollMe();
                counter++;
                }
            );
         down = true;   
        } 
}
});
```